# What are the differences between difficulty levels in SOTS: The Pit?

Tags: sword-of-the-stars-the-pit

When starting a character, there are four difficulty levels:

```
Easy
Normal
Hard
Insane
```

What changes based on the difficulty chosen? The wiki shows that experience gained changes, but is there anything else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, a lot of things seem to change with difficulty. From a quick look at Easy, compared to my regular runs on Hard (and a few early peeks at Insane):

- Experience you gain decreases with difficulty.
- You get more health on level-up on lower difficulties.
- Your damage decreases with difficulty, enemies' damage increases.
- Stronger enemies appear sooner and more often on higher difficulties.
- More map objects (boxes, recharge hubs, stuff like that) spawn on lower difficulties, and new objects seem to appear sooner on lower difficulties.
- Map objects seem to spawn damaged or ruined less often on lower difficulties.
- More and rarer items drop more often on lower difficulties.

What does not seem to change:

- Hunger and food
- Durability, power, ammo and repair mechanics
- Traps
- Status effects
- Number of charges in hubs and crafting stations